# Form is still "TopMost" although it is set to false

Tags: winforms, forms, topmost

I don't know how to solve this. I have a Form2 which is opened via a Form1. Although the option "TopMost" is set to "false" the Form2 is still in the foreground. Clicking on the Form1 somewhere does nothing. Is there a way to solve this and let the Form2 pop up again into the Foreground when the button is clicked which opens it?

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (form2.Visible == false)
    {
        form2 = new Form2(this);
        form2.Show(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: My psychic debugger says that you created an owned window, it always overlaps the owner.  Use Show() instead of Show(owner) to display it.

Comment: Is `Form2` opened modeless (using `Show()`) or modally (using `ShowDialog()`)?. If modally, then it's not "topmost", but you can't select any other window. If modeless, then probably you set the owner to `Form1`

Comment: How can I cahnge the owner? I call the Form with "form2.Show(this);" but I think my Form1 is already the owner

Comment: So even when I set Form1 TopMost to true it doesn't change

Comment: It is exactly as my debugger predicted.  Use `form2.Show();`, delete *this*.

Comment: Ok that helped but when I click the button again I want the Form2 to show up in the foreground again. Now it stays in the background

Comment: ah ok. form2.BringToFront(); solves it. Thanks for your help!